# Why Gitlab container works with docker-compose.yml v1, but not v2?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I'm trying to upgrade docker-compose file (v1 to v2) which contains the gitlab service.

But with docker-compose file v2, the gitlab container doesn't work, it seems to restart in a loop and I get the following error in a loop in the logs :

```
gitlab_1      | ERROR: 
gitlab_1      |   Please configure the database connection.
gitlab_1      |   Refer http://git.io/wkYhyA for more information.
gitlab_1      |   Cannot continue without a database. Aborting...
```

The other containers/services in docker-compose.yml work, but gitlab container keeps restarting :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS                                NAMES
0fc7c9e5fed3        sameersbn/gitlab:13.12.4                              "/sbin/entrypoint.sh…"   About a minute ago   Restarting (1) 42 seconds ago                                        gitlab_gitlab_1
ca58e9c97153        sameersbn/postgresql:12-20200524                      "/sbin/entrypoint.sh"    About a minute ago   Up About a minute               5432/tcp                             gitlab_postgresql_1
4799998c8ebb        sameersbn/redis:latest                                "/sbin/entrypoint.sh"    About a minute ago   Up About a minute               6379/tcp                             gitlab_redis_1
```

Docker version : 18.06.3-ce, build d7080c1

Docker-compose version : 1.28.5, build c4eb3a1f

Docker-compose.yml version 1 :

```
postgresql:
  image: sameersbn/postgresql:12-20200524
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=mypassword
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
    - DB_EXTENSION=pg_trgm,btree_gist
  volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /var/test/gitlab/postgresql_lib:/var/lib/postgresql
    - /var/test/gitlab/postgresql_run:/run/postgresql
gitlab:
  image: sameersbn/gitlab:13.12.4
  restart: unless-stopped
  links:
  - redis:redisio
  - postgresql:postgresql
  ports:
  - "22:22"
  environment:
    - GITLAB_BACKUP_DIR=/backups
    - GITLAB_HOST=gitlab.loc
    - GITLAB_PORT=80
    - GITLAB_SSH_PORT=22
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=Secretxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=Secretxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE=Secretxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    - GITLAB_EMAIL=gitlab@test.com
    - GITLAB_EMAIL_REPLY_TO=gitlab@test.com
    - GITLAB_TIMEZONE=Paris
    - GITLAB_NOTIFY_ON_BROKEN_BUILDS=true
    - GITLAB_NOTIFY_PUSHER=true
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=gitlab.loc
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
  volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /srv/backups/gitlab:/backups
    - /var/test/gitlab/home:/home/git/data

redis:
  image: sameersbn/redis:latest
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Docker-compose.yml version 2 :

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  postgresql:
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:12-20200524
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - DB_USER=gitlab
      - DB_PASS=mypassword
      - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
      - DB_EXTENSION=pg_trgm,btree_gist
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/test/gitlab/postgresql_lib:/var/lib/postgresql
      - /var/test/gitlab/postgresql_run:/run/postgresql
  gitlab:
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:13.12.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - "22:22"
    environment:
      - GITLAB_BACKUP_DIR=/backups
      - GITLAB_HOST=gitlab.loc
      - GITLAB_PORT=80
      - GITLAB_SSH_PORT=22
      - GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=Secretxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=Secretxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE=Secretxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - GITLAB_EMAIL=gitlab@test.com
      - GITLAB_EMAIL_REPLY_TO=gitlab@test.com
      - GITLAB_TIMEZONE=Paris
      - GITLAB_NOTIFY_ON_BROKEN_BUILDS=true
      - GITLAB_NOTIFY_PUSHER=true
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=gitlab.loc
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /srv/backups/gitlab:/backups
      - /var/test/gitlab/home:/home/git/data

  redis:
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

The only real difference I see is the removal of `links` option and the file format structure in version 2.

For `links` option, I've also tried replacing it with the `depends_on` option, but it doesn't work.

What do I need to change to make my version 2 file work like version 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely replace the [`links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#links) since it's long deprecated (Also see the big red alert telling you what to use instead in the docs). But [`dependsOn`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) is not the replacement, it just defines the startup order of the containers (or to be more precise: docker figures the startup order out for you based on this). You need a way to enable communication between your containers. [User-defined bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) are the way to go here. You need to connect the services which should communicate with each other to the same network.

```yaml
version: "2.3"
services:
  postgresql:
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:12-20200524
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - my-network # connect to created network
    environment:
      - DB_USER=gitlab
      - DB_PASS=mypassword
      - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
      - DB_EXTENSION=pg_trgm,btree_gist
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/test/gitlab/postgresql_lib:/var/lib/postgresql
      - /var/test/gitlab/postgresql_run:/run/postgresql
  gitlab:
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:13.12.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - my-network # connect to created network
    ports:
    - "22:22"
    environment:
      - GITLAB_BACKUP_DIR=/backups
      - GITLAB_HOST=gitlab.loc
      - GITLAB_PORT=80
      - GITLAB_SSH_PORT=22
      - GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=Secretxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=Secretxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE=Secretxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - GITLAB_EMAIL=gitlab@test.com
      - GITLAB_EMAIL_REPLY_TO=gitlab@test.com
      - GITLAB_TIMEZONE=Paris
      - GITLAB_NOTIFY_ON_BROKEN_BUILDS=true
      - GITLAB_NOTIFY_PUSHER=true
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=gitlab.loc
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /srv/backups/gitlab:/backups
      - /var/test/gitlab/home:/home/git/data

  redis:
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - my-network # connect to created network
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
# tell docker to create a user-defined network
networks:
  my-network:
```

This should enable `gitlab` to connect to the database.

> Also, please be aware that the `docker compose` version and the docker compose file version are two different things. The neweset version of the docker compose file is `3.8`, you are using `2.3` so consider to update there as well (see [Docker docs - compatibility matrix](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#compose-and-docker-compatibility-matrix)).

Comment: Thanks for this anwser, but it still doesn't work... The problem may be due to the Docker engine version and the old OS version (debian 8). 

I'll have to try it out in a new test environment.